# Streaming responses with chunked transfer encoding

Tags: async-await, dotnet-httpclient, transfer-encoding

We have a small proxy server written in .net. A simplified version of the core proxy functionality:

```
builder.Run(async ctx =>
        {
            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                await client.SendAsync(BuildRequest(), HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead)
                .ContinueWith(t => t.Result.Content.CopyToAsync(ctx.Response.Body));
            }
        });
```

The idea is that the proxy will simply stream any downstream responses back to calling client as raw as possible.

[image: problem]

The connection between the proxy and the service seems to working fine, always returning the 17kb of data i expect. The problem is between the client and the proxy, where sending the same request results in a response truncated somewhere between 0 and 17kb in length, apparently without reason.

- When copying content from the service response to the client response, how can i tell when all of the content has been received? I know that chunked transfers are terminated by 0 length chunk, so do i need to check for this manually, or is this something handled by the httpresponse instance itself?